# How to get WCF-StructureMap-NHibernate to work together?

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, structuremap

Can anyone point me to an up to date example of how to integrate all 3
of these tools? I have found some examples but they seem out dated.
Here are the examples that I have found.

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/09/16/integrating-structuremap-and-nhibernate-with-wcf.aspx
http://andreasohlund.net/2009/04/27/unitofwork-in-wcf-using-structuremap/ <-- Doesn't address nhibernate
http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/05/26/structuremap-wcf-nhibernate-part-1/
http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/05/27/structuremap-wcf-nhibernate-part-2/

I started trying the coreycoogan example, but I ran into a few issues.
He shows creating StructureMap registry where a dependency is injected
into the constructor of the Registry, but he doesn't show how to do
that part. I have never seen that example with StructureMap
registries. All of the examples that I have seen have a parameterless
contstructor.

Is this possible, if so how? I am making a call to the
ObjectFactory.Initialize method in a Bootstrapper class that makes a
call to the scanner with default conventions and a call the
LookForRegistries method. This finds all of Registry classes except
for the one that needs the dependency injected. I would assume since I
don't have it wired in correctly or it is not possible.

Here is small part of that code example for the registry that is in
part 2 of his post:

```
/// <summary>  
/// A StructureMap registry for telling the container how to resolve an ISession request.  
/// This must be instantiated and added to the SM configuration so it has an instance of the  
/// SessionFactory to use.  
/// </summary>  
public class WcfNHibernateRegistry : Registry  
{  
    public WcfNHibernateRegistry(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)  
    {
        For<NHibernate.ISession>()  
            .Use(() => sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession());  
    }  
}
```

Comment: It appears to me that your actual question has nothing to do with WCF or NHibernate, but is more along the lines of 'how to config  StructureMap when the Registry class needs an injected dependency", no?

Comment: Yes and no. I would like to find a good example of how to integrate these technologies. So, this question really has 2 parts: (1) Where is a good example. (2) In the example I chose, how would I solve the Registry question.

Comment: I've done something similar, but I don't have the time to create for you a sample that would answer this question.  If you could break it down into more specific questions, I may well be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the StructureMap initialization...

The LookForRegistries method only finds Registry classes that have zero-parameter constructors.  This makes sense - StructureMap is not initialized and ready to use yet; it isn't ready to inject dependencies.  If you want to inject a dependency into your Registry class, you need to do it manually.  (If there are other methods, I am unaware of them.)

If you follow 'example 1' from here http://structuremap.net/structuremap/RegistryDSL.htm#section2 you can do so, but I believe the example assumes you'll be using the resulting Container instance and not necessarily the ObjectFactory static methods.  (Not sure how use of registering types within a specific container works.)

Alternatively, you can remove the constructor parameter.  I believe this will work:

```
public class WcfNHibernateRegistry : Registry
{
    public WcfNHibernateRegistry()
    {
        For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton().Use(() => {
            var cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        });

        For<ISession>().Use(() => {
            var fac = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>();
            return fac.GetCurrentSession();
        });
    }
}
```